# "equal symbol expected" error in JSP while fecthing values for the 'select' tag from properties file

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

Using Struts 2 `<s:select>` tag, I have the below piece of code where the values for drop down are hard-coded.

```xml
<s:select name="xxx" id="xxx" list="#{'1':'emailON', '0':'emailOFF'}" value="abc.xyz"/>
```

I would want to read these values (emailON & emailOFF) from properties file instead.

Tried this approach where the corresponding text names are mapped in the properties file:

```xml
<s:select name="emailOnOff" id="emailOnOff" list="#{'1': 's:text name="label.myaccount.emailON"', '0': 's:text name="label.myaccount.emailOFF"'}" value="abc.xyz"/>
```

But receive the below error:

```xml
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /xx/my_account.jsp (line: xx, column: xx) equal symbol expected
```

How do we actually pass the values if they are present in the properties file?

Comment: P.S.:I have not included the '<' & '>' before and after the struts tag as there's an issue while rendering it in the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use nested JSP tags in Struts tag's attributes. To retrieve the property from the resource bundle you can use [`getText()`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html#getText-java.lang.String-) in OGNL expression.

> Gets a message based on a message key or if no message is found the provided key is returned.

---

**The code:**

```xhtml
<s:select name="emailOnOff" 
  id="emailOnOff" 
  list="#{
    '1': getText("label.myaccount.emailON"), 
    '0': getText("label.myaccount.emailOFF")
  }" 
  value="abc.xyz"
/>
```

---

Comment: I get the same error. Will it be able to translate without embedding it in a scriptlet?

Comment: Tried this way as well. No luck though     `list="#{'1' : '%{getText("label.myaccount.emailON")}', '0' : '%{getText("label.myaccount.emailOFF")}'}"`

Comment: I don't think you did, this is not the same code I've posted.